# Install Apache mod_evasive on Windows

Tags: windows, apache-2.4

I want to install Apache mod_evasive on a Windows Server with Apache 2.4 running on it, but I don't know how to compile the mod_evasive24.c file. Is there any place where I can download the compiled .so file of the module?